# How to declare war on dead race or to remove their starbases some other way?

Tags: stardrive, stardrive-2

I have killed a race.
Then I got a prompt by them that I shouldn't fly in their space, I just ignored it but I saw the option to 'Declare War' and didn't press it at that time.
Later I found a sector with minerals where I would like to build my starbase, however, the dead race has starbase there already and I can't seem to kill it, the only option is 'Withdraw'.

[image]

In the politics screen, there is no option to interact with them, so I can't declare war but then how do I remove the leftover starbases?

[image]

**Is there a workaround, without loading savegame?**